# Inserting a cell in an existing Sheet in NPOI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, npoi

Can somebody please help me out. I need to insert a cell in an existing sheet. I'm using NPOI library for processing Excel data.
Thanks.

This is what I want to achieve. I have loaded an excel in a Sheet object. My target is to insert few columns in the existing sheet and save it to another excel file. I tried to create a cell on the index where i intended the cell is getting created by it is overwriting the previous cell at that position. I need a functinoality wherin I can insert a cell in between two cells.
Below is the code.

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
 {
            wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
            NPOI.SS.UserModel.ISheet sheet = wb.GetSheetAt(0);
            NPOI.SS.UserModel.IRow headerRow = sheet.GetRow(1);
            int columnCount = headerRow.Cells.Count;
            int rowCount = sheet.LastRowNum;
            string ColumnContractStartDate = string.Empty;

            //adding header cells at index 7 and 8
            HSSFCell cell7 = (HSSFCell) headerRow.CreateCell(7);
            cell7.SetCellValue("* Contract Start Date");

            HSSFCell cell8 = (HSSFCell) headerRow.CreateCell(8);
            cell8.SetCellValue("* Contract End Date");

              //adding row cells at index 7 and 8
                for (int j = 2; j < rowCount; j++)
                {
                    NPOI.SS.UserModel.IRow dataRow = sheet.GetRow(j);
                    //PFS ROws
                    dataRow.CreateCell(7).SetCellValue("");
                    dataRow.CreateCell(8).SetCellValue("");
                 }

                FileStream file = new FileStream("F:\\ShareDataFeed\\test12.xls", FileMode.Create);
             wb.Write(file);
             file.Close();
             fs.Close();
   }
```

Comment: This isn't how you should ask a question on SO. You need to tell us what you have tried and hopefully show some code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks. I have done the needful.

Comment: Have you tried CreateCell?